# British English spelling: “gripped” or “gript”?

Tags: british-english, orthography, past-participles

Hello what is the correct British English spelling of the word 'gripped' or 'gript'?

According to [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/gript):

> **gript**
>   verb
>   1. a past participle and simple past tense of *grip*.
>
> **verb** (used without object), *gripped* or *gript*, *gripping*.
>
> e.g. *The boat now run ‘pon the top ov me; I was gript by the scruff ov the neck, and dragg’d into it.*
>    <sub>Humours of Irish Life</sub>

Comment: Since they both would be pronounced the same way (unlike *"learned"* and *"learnt"*), there's no reason not to spell it *"gripped"*. Look it up in a dictionary. If it doesn't give a past tense, then it's regular and thus *"gripped"*.

Comment: Thank you for your response Peter.. Could/would you inform me please; which is the correct/exact spelling is it 'gripped' or is it 'gript'

Comment: There are lots of [respectable](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/grip) and [useful](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grip) dictionaries [available](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/grip_2) on the internet. Dictionary.com is apparently not one.

Comment: A book entitled *Humours of Irish Life* is likely to use non-standard spellings to reflect the humorous way Irish people speak.

Comment: Apologies Mari-Lou A this is the first time I have used this site and my first post.. I don't know 'one' had to include any research.. I did though; look up both 'gripped' & 'gript', before posting my question; however I just didn't get a conclusive answer. I am I am severely dyslexic and I wanted to be pedantic & obtain the correct spelling. I understand for future postings and questions, that I should imclude any research I have done prior ot posting my question. Sorry if I have misused the site

Comment: No need to apologize (apologise), you haven't misused the site in the slightest, but users appreciate questions from people who have first attempted to find an answer-which very often includes looking up a word in a dictionary, and then *explaining* why they are still confused. As first questions go, this wasn't bad at all  (after the edit).

Comment: Interestingly, [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grip) gives << **grip** vb, grips, gripping or gripped>> I suspect they've botched deleting _gript_.

Comment: I have learnt a new word today, from dictionary.com. I can't find it in other dictionaries, though.

Comment: Hello again Mari-Lou A- As I am a novice to Stack Exchange; would you  please inform me why my original question was edited? That way I can learn to submit questions in the correct format in future. Apologies too prevail on you again. Many thanks Corinne

Comment: Second, I was quick to edit this question because I knew it risked getting closed, there was no research. It is not enough to say "I have done some research" You must show/share your research, very often a link and a citation from a dictionary is enough. I included the research (Dictionary.com) in this question. This proved to visitors that *grip* could be spelt two ways: *gripped* and *gript*. I also replaced the CAPS in the question title with lower-case letters. If you look at *any* question, no one writes in CAPS.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A..You have been (once more) exceptionally helpful to me. I have learnt today (from you) not to make my 'request' in capitals. As well as showing what research I have done, prior to posting my question. I will also try & ascertain that ant question I post, hasn't already been asked before. I will also endeavour to read the Stack Exchange 'guidelines' to get a better protective/handle on how I should, in future, address my questions/post.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A.. I was too long winded in the first response.. Thank you very much, for going to the all the time & immense trouble to guide me through my initial (teething)/clumsy) problems/attempts!  As I explained yesterday I am a novice to this site... well any forum site really.. I WILL get it right! Enjoy the remainder of your day. Thanks again. Kind regards form a somewhat cold & damp England!! Corinne

Comment: Brava! see I got a notification in my inbox that you posted a message to me! I will now delete a few of my comments, which are not strictly connected to this  question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Australian English, which for the most part is similar to British English, I have never come across “gript”. “Gripped” is the only form of the word that I have ever come across. I suspect that the former is probably old English, and no longer in use, or looking at the usage example, possibly a “dialect spelling”.

Comment: Thank you Paul for your clear and concise explanation. I will 'go' with 'gripped' from now onwards. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Middle English Dictionary](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=28PD7_jfnRYC&pg=PA378&dq=%22gript%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFMQ6AEwCWoVChMIybS8r8bRxwIVqSnbCh2o4A18#v=onepage&q=%22gript%22&f=false), Volume 4 By Hans Kurath, gript was one of the spellings all those hundreds of years ago.

Beyond that we can look at **[Google ngram: gript,gripped](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gript%2Cgripped&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgript%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgripped%3B%2Cc0)**. From the graph we can see that the 'gripped' spelling took off from 1850 onwards.

Comment: Thank you Chasly for your trouble. I have now 'grasped it' that 'gripped' is the correct spelling. I appreciate the trouble you went to. Corinne

Comment: In poetry from the period of Shakespeare, Milton, etc you will also find "gripp'd". The reason was that "-ed" at the end of a word was counted as a separate syllable in the rhythm of the poem, in the same way that "silent" vowels are still counted as syllables in French poetry. The apostrophe made it clear that the word should be pronounced with only one syllable not two.  In Scots, these words were often spelled "-it" not "-ed". For example "He grippit Nelly hard and fast" in http://www.robertburns.org/works/74.shtml. In that poem, two syllables *are* intended, to fit the rhythm of the verse.

Comment: Good point.  In fact around Shakespeare's time many such endings were changing and spelling was far from standardised.

Comment: +1 Just by the way, Kurath's been superseded by the online [*MED*](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/med/), also from Michigan.

Comment: @alephzero Just to be clear, Scots, although very similar to English and mostly mutually comprehensible, is actually a separate language. There's nothing wrong with using it as an example of the same phenomenon in a different (and very closely related) language as long as the reader is not left with the impression that Scots is a variant of English. Since Scots is not well-known I just thought I point that out.